# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'DataProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am new to typescript with reactjs. Here I tried to display data which is coming from data file which looks something like this see below.

After this I am grabing object with same id and display that object on screen for that I used destructuring of object like this.

Here type script is complaining about types which i have added but still error is not going away.

> Error Type '{ id: number; img: any; title: string; subtitle: string; price: number; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'DataProps'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'DataProps'.

```
   interface DataProps {
      img: ImageSourcePropType;
    
      title: string;
      subtitle: string;
    }
    
        const productId = route.params.productId;
          const dataDisplay = data.find((el, index) => {
   

          if (el.id !== productId) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      return el.id === productId;
    }
          });
        
          const { img, title, subtitle }: DataProps = dataDisplay;  <--- here typescript is complaining about
```

> dummydata.ts

```
 export const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        img: require("../../assets/food-1.png"),
        title: "Pizza",
        subtitle: "With Beef Mushroom",
        price: 12,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        img: require("../../assets/food-2.png"),
        title: "Pizza",
        subtitle: "With Beef Mushroom",
        price: 12,
      },
```

Comment: You need to check that `dataDisplay !== undefined` first.

Comment: ` if (el.id !== productId) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      return el.id === productId;
    }`

Comment: i did this still it is showing same thing

Comment: I don't see it in your code. For the code you posted it's an expected error as you must check `dataDisplay !== undefined` first.

Comment: can you please show this in code. I m not getting where to put this.

Comment: Before you do any read from `dataDisplay` check `dataDisplay !== undefined`